# Is the data in Vec<T> always densely packed?

Tags: rust

It is a common pattern to see this 'shortcut' code in rust:

```
unsafe fn any_as_u8_slice<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
    ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(
        (p as *const T) as *const u8,
        ::std::mem::size_of::<T>(),
    )
}
```

ie. Given a struct, unsafely convert the underlying pointer to `&[u8]` to read the bytes.

However, is it valid to take the same approach when using `Vec<T>`?

For example, this appears to work:

```
use std::mem::size_of;
use std::slice::from_raw_parts;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: u8,
    pub y: u8,
    pub z: u8,
}


fn as_bytes(data: &[Point]) -> &[u8] {
    unsafe { 
        let raw_pointer = data.as_ptr();
        from_raw_parts(raw_pointer as *const u8, size_of::<Point>() * data.len())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let points = vec![Point{x: 0u8, y: 1u8, z: 2u8}, Point{x: 3u8, y: 4u8, z: 5u8}];
    let slice = points.as_slice();
    println!("{:?}", slice);

    let bytes = as_bytes(slice);
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    
    assert!(bytes.len() == 6);
    assert!(bytes[0] == 0u8);
    assert!(bytes[1] == 1u8);
    assert!(bytes[2] == 2u8);
    assert!(bytes[3] == 3u8);
    assert!(bytes[4] == 4u8);
    assert!(bytes[5] == 5u8);
}
```

...but is it reliable to assume that `Vec<T>` is represented as a single contiguous block of data this way?

The documentation on https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation says:

> If a Vec has allocated memory, then the memory it points to is on the heap (as defined by the allocator Rust is configured to use by default), and its pointer points to len initialized, contiguous elements in order (what you would see if you coerced it to a slice), followed by capacity-len logically uninitialized, contiguous elements.

...but I'm not really sure if I understand what it means. Does this actually mean that for `Vec<T>` the underlying pointer is to a block of memory of length `size_of::<T>` * length of the Vec?

Comment: The data allocated by `Vec<T>` is a single contiguous block of `T`, but it's not exactly the same as in the `Point` example, because you can't just take the address of the `Vec` to inspect the data of the `T` - the `Vec` itself only contains the triple of (pointer, length, capacity). To get to the `T`s, you need to obtain the pointer to the allocated block using `Vec::as_ptr()` or equivalent. Apologies if this is completely obvious, it's just not entirely clear from the question what you're asking about.

Comment: AIUI, the underlying pointer points to a block of memory of length `size_of::<T> * capacity` bytes, of which the first `size_of::<T> * length` bytes are initialized. That, provided that `capacity > 0 && size_of::<T> > 0`, or else the pointer offers no guarantees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `Vec<T>` can be made into something that can be treated as a pointer to a block of memory of length `std::mem::size_of::<T>() times the length of Vec`.

There is one caveat, as what you are actually interested in is the `slice` of `T`, which the `Vec` can provide; the `Vec` itself should be considered an implementation detail. Besides that:

1. A `Vec<T>` [can deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods) to a slice `[T]`. Take that `slice`.
2. The [Rust Reference defines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#slice-layout) that a `slice` has the same layout as the section of the `Array` they slice. So when we deref from a `Vec<T>` to a `[T]`, this slice of length `n` is guaranteed to have the same memory layout as an array `[T; n]`.
3. The [Rust References defines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#array-layout) the memory layout of an `Array`:

   > Arrays are laid out so that the nth element of the array is offset
   > from the start of the array by `n * the size of the type` bytes. An
   > array of `[T; n]` has a size of `size_of::<T>() * n` and the same
   > alignment of `T`.
4. We know `n` (from `[T]`) and we know "`the size of the type` bytes" (via `mem::size_of<T>()`). Since all members of an array must be fully initialized at all times, and given the two sentences from the paragraph above, we know *it is safe to access all bytes up until `mem::size_of<T>() * length of Vec`* (actually length of `slice`, which introduces the array memory layout rule).

To make use of all that, you should make sure that you get a `slice` of the `Vec` first, use [`as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr) on the slice, and cast the raw pointer you get. This ensures the sequence of definitions as above. Your `fn as_bytes(data: &[Point]) -> &[u8]` is exactly correct.

Comment: "we know it is safe to access all bytes up until mem::size_of<T>() * length of Vec" - only if there are no padding bytes. This applies to the code in the OP too, however.

Comment: @Cerberus, AFAICS accessing a padding byte is not undefined behaviour but results in a `MaybeUninit<u8>`, which is what it is.

Comment: Only if you read it as `MaybeUninit<u8>`. If you read it as `u8`, it's UB.

Comment: @Cerberus: I recall having read about padding bytes in Rust, but I cannot find the source. Do you have any link or reference about this?